# Encoding of the Canadian PostBar barcodes

Tags: encoding, barcode

I am working on a software to encode postal addresses using the PostBar barcode symbology in use in Canada.

I can't find the relevant information for these codes. Wikipedia does describe PostBars, but with a caveat saying that the article is about the D12 type, whereas the Canadian Post actually uses the types D52.01/D82.01/S52.40 and S82.39, which are different and undocumented. (I also know the "CANADA POST CORPORATION 4-STATE BAR CODE HANDBOOK" document, which doesn't help.)

I need the specifics of the encoding of the fields (DCI, Postal Code, Address Locator...) and the parameters of Reed-Solomon parity bits.

I am not after an implementation, which I am able to craft myself. Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: There is [this](https://uae.souq.com/ae-en/articles-on-canada-post-including-postal-codes-in-canada-purolator-courier-postbar-cpc-binary-barcode-canadian-subnational-postal-abbreviations-by-hephaestus-books-paperback-15641428/i/) book, but I don'n think it really will help. Try to write an email to a Canadian post office.

Comment: Based on this thread: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APostBar it seems like Canada Post PostBars is a proprietary format. If not reverse engineer - and assuming this topic is covered by legislation - you would need to find a Canadian citizen to make a Access to Information request at Canada Post https://www.canadapost.ca/web/en/pages/aboutus/details.page?article=accessinformation

Comment: @MorrisonChang: unfortunately, I couldn't access the "reverse engineering" explanations.

Comment: Have you investigated whether their API contains the details you need? https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/tour/whatare.jsf

Comment: @Doug: I can't access this API (and suspect that it won't expose the required info).

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I could find on the subject. It is not much, I'm afraid:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_Post#Barcodes

Canada Post uses a 13 character barcode for their pre-printed labels. Bar codes consist of two letters, followed by eight sequence digits, and a ninth digit which is the check digit. The last two characters are the letters CA. The check digit seems to ignore the letters and only concern itself with the first 8 numeric digits. The scheme is to multiply each of those 8 digits by a different weighting factor, (8 6 4 2 3 5 9 7). Add up the total of all of these multiplications and divide by 11. The remainder after dividing by 11 gives a number from 0 to 10. Subtracting this from 11 gives a number from 1 to 11. That result is the check digit, except in the two cases where it is 10 or 11. If 10 it is then changed to a 0, and if 11 then it is changed to a 5. The check digit may be used to verify if a barcode scan is correct, or if a manual entry of the barcode is correct.

And as bonus, an explanation of the barcodes, in Dutch:

https://www.postnl.nl/Images/Brochure-KIX-code-van-PostNL_tcm10-10210.pdf

Comment: This is unrelated to the PostBars, sorry. They are also totally different from the KIX (wich are a simplified form of RM4SCC).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we ( Canada Post ) use PostBar anymore. Management made adoption too much of a pain for the mailer so it died. I haven't seen one on an envelope in years.  Now that OCR tech is so good it wouldn't help that much to include a PostBar anyway.
What they should have done is given away software that printed up the address labels in alpha-numeric order of the postal code and printed a bunch of positional marks on the top fold of the envelope based on that same postal code. That way a postal clerk need not even take the mail out of the box to see where it should be shipped to.  LVM's (large volume mailers) would do this for a rebate on their bill.
Ase for smaller businesses or the general public we should have just soled them prepaid envelopes in 2 or 3 standard sizes for a dime less than the cost of a stamp alone. A standard envelop can have a dedicated spot for a machine readable postal code. I would have gone with good old public-domain Braille! printed or in sharpy:-) Oh well I'm rambling now I'll stop.

Comment: Thank you for caring to answer and provide these details.